# MySQL Query between two items

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has 4 columns: `id, twitter_id, date, time`. I'd like to select all the rows which `date` value is 17-03-09 and  the `time`, that they are between 9:00 and 9:59.
Is that possible with MySQL? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `id`, `twitter_id`, `date`, `time`
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `date` = '2009-03-17' AND `time` >= '9:00' AND `time` < '10:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT    *
FROM      your_table
WHERE     date = '2009-03-17'
  AND     HOUR(time) = 9
```

possibly, assuming you mean 9am. If you mean PM, switch the condition to 21